# What does "Global EU" mean in the context of smartphone versions?

Tags: xiaomi

While browsing smartphone offers, I encountered several offers like "Xiaomi Mi9 6/64GB Global EU". What does "Global EU" mean in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the ROM version installed on the phone indicating the region. Manufacturers ship different ROMs depending on the region. Someone living in Europe will have a different ROM than one living in Africa or Asia. You can even find difference in ROMs within a continent or region.

Usually with Xiaomi phones, you have the Global and China ROMs. Then (if I am not mistaken -- someone corrects me here), the Global versions is divided in EU, Russia, India, etc depending on the market. Global EU is just the ROM version for the EU market.